# asp.net MVC 4 submit from with ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Student student)
    { //somecode..
```

and i want to submit this from:

```
<form method="post" action="/student/create"> 
<!-- the from contents-->
```

how to submit this from using Ajax call
i need the JQuery ajax call that lets this form submitted.

and i want to make sure about datatype ,
thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this

```
var form = $('#formId');
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  async: true,
  type: "POST",
  url: form.attr('action'),
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
 }
});
```

Comment: form = document.forms[2]---
when i use form.serialize() , i have type error [serialize is not function] 
JQuery already included..
how to solve it?

Comment: can you please tell me that how can we trigger default mvc validation before submitting form?

Comment: @UmarAbbas you can try like this:- http://jsfiddle.net/cfwx3Ld5/ and use razor form instread of html

Answer (score 5):

Use this, assuming you are using **razor** views:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions(){
HttpMethod = "POST",
    Url = "your controller",
    OnComplete = "some client event"
})
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>This is a demo form.</legend>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: You're missing a end parens in your using.  S/B:  OnComplete = "some client event"}))

Answer (score 1):

Well it would look something like (that's without looking at your view bindings):

```
// serialize your form into JSON - maybe you have a different method of doing it
var serializedForm = $("#YourFormId").serialize();

// post it to the server
$.post("/student/create", serializedForm)
    .done(function (response) { 
       // it's done
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) { 
       // something bad happened
    });
```